# handling n checkboxes in a react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox, react-hooks, state

How could I do if I want to handle n sets of vars of the type [variable, setVariable] so I can declare n states in a component

The proble is that I could have n checkboxes, and I have to handle the value for those n checkboxes

Comment: The question begs another question, what have you tried, why didn't it work. It seems very little effort was made to produce your question

Comment: Have you tried using an array of n length and use the checkbox index to change the values dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't fully understand your question, but I assume you wanna store n checkbox references to do something with them later on. So here's one solution for that

```
const checkboxes = useRef({});

...

{data.map((x, idx) => <input type="checkbox" ref={(el) => checkboxes.current[idx] = el)}>
```

You will get references of all the checkboxes in it.

If my answer is wrong or this isn't right, tell me in the comments, I'll try to understand and solve it better

Comment: Also note: This demo assumes the order and number of checkboxes remain same. If the number changes during rendering or any re-arranging happen, you should give an ID to each single checkbox element, and then it will be `checkboxes.current[YOUR_ID] = el`